# Change column value with same ID's to a new value based on Max Date

Tags: mysql, sql, ssms, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to Change the description of a column based on the Max date in SqlSMS. 
For example:

```
ID    | Description | Period   
====================    
N282  | FSV Trivex  | 2016-06-30    
N276  | Crystal AB  | 2016-06-30   
N282  | FSV 1.600   | 2014-10-31   
N276  | Vanity xxx  | 2014-08-09
```

The issue here in that 2 IDs have different descriptions. I want to set the description value of the ID equal to the description of the MAX DATE.

SO I want to get this at the end,

```
ID    | Description | Period
====================
N282  | FSV Trivex  | 2016-06-30    
N276  | Crystal AB  | 2016-06-30   
N282  | FSV Trivex  | 2014-10-31    
N276  | Crystal AB  | 2014-08-09
```

Now, all the descriptions fro the ID are the same.

There are thousands of items, but I just want to get an idea of how to accomplish this with joins.

Thanks you.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
select t1.ID, t2.Description, t1.Period 
from tbl t1
inner join
   (select ID, Description  
   from tbl
   group by ID 
   having max(Period)) t2
on t1.ID = t2.ID;
```

Check this.. 
<kbd>[**SQL Fiddle HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dd58c/1)</kbd>